# other multivariable version of Hensel's Lemma

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

In advance, sorry for my english.

In [this notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/multivarhensel.pdf) there's a multivariable version of the $|f(a)|_p<|f'(a)|_p$ version of Hensel's Lemma. I tried to adapt it to a proof  for a multivariable version of the $f'(a)\ne 0\ \mod\ p$ Hensel's lemma. Basically, all I did was replace one univariate Hensel's lemma for  the other, but as i'm new in the p adic world I am not so confident about it, I'd thank a lot for some comment.

Also, if someone knows of a book from somewhere where this is stated, I would thank the reference (if there is, I haven't found it). I'm mostly interested in this phenomena in ideal-adic version on some good ring.

So here is the statement, where $||\cdot||_p$ denotes the maximum of the $|\cdot|_p$ of a tuple, and $\nabla f$ is the tuple of partial derivatives of $f$

> If $f(X_1 \dots X_d)\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ and some $\mathbf{a} \in\mathbb{Z}_p^d $ satisfies
> $$f(\mathbf{a})=0\ mod\ p$$
> $$||\nabla f(\mathbf{a})||_p\ne 0$$
> then $f$ has a zero in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ that equals $\mathbf{a}$ modulo $p$.

Here's the proof

> As $||\nabla f(\mathbf{a})||_p\ne 0$, there's a coordinate $j$, fixed from now on, such that $|\partial f / \partial X_j(\mathbf{a})|_p\ne 0$. We now define a polynomial $g$ in one variable by $$g(X)=f(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_j-1,X,a_j+1,\dots,a_d)\in\mathbb{Z}_p[X].$$
> Then $g(a_j)=f(\mathbf{a})$ and $g'(a_j)=\partial f / \partial X_j(\mathbf{a})$, so $g(a_j)=0\ mod\ p$ and $g'(a_j)\ne 0 \mod\ p$.  Univariate Hensel's lemma can now be used, and there's $\alpha_j\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $g(\alpha_j)=0$ and $\alpha = a_j \ mod\ p$. If we define $\alpha_i=a_i$ for $i\ne j$ and $\mathbf{\alpha}$ as $(\alpha_1,\dots ,\alpha_d)$, then $\mathbf{\alpha}\in\mathbb{Z}_p^d$ is a zero for $f$, and equals $\mathbf{a}$ modulo $p$.

---

:)

Comment: I think you are looking at Theorem 2.1 in the linked file. You have a very bad typographical error: $||(\nabla f)(a)||_p \not= 0$ is not a good hypothesis. When $d = 1$ (single-variable polynomials), such a hypothesis says $f'(a) \not= 0$ and it's wrong that if $f(a) \equiv 0 \bmod p$ and $|f'(a)|_p \not= 0$ then you should expect $f(x)$ has a root in $\mathbf Z_p$.  Try $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, $p=2$, and $a = 1$. For $f(x) \in \mathbf Z_p[x]$, do not confuse the conditions $|f'(a)|_p \not= 0$ and $f'(a) \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$ (the second one is the same as $|f'(a)|_p = 1$).

Comment: Theorem 2.1 in that file is already a version of Hensel's lemma for multivariable polynomials, but not a very serious one (it doesn't make essential use of all the variables in the polynomial) because its proof immediately reduces to the single variable case, unlike Theorem 3.3 there.

Comment: Many thanks! I was definitely confusing $f'(a)\ne 0 \ mod \ p$ with $|f'(a)|_p\ne 0$. So the argument would work with $||nabla f||_p=1$, but that's included in theorem 2.1